# jquery onclick go to top of page without scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

By click on a button, I want to go to the top of the page. but it should not scroll to the top (no animation), instead it should go immediately to the top (just like a new page load).
Is this possible with jquery?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

`window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord);`

Comment: Hello! thank you very much! It works well, but it looks a little bit weird, I can still see that it is scrolling very fast to the top.

Comment: This may be dependent on your browser. Modern browsers force certain interaction.

Comment: You could try using an `animate` and setting the time lapse to 0

Comment: I understand! Thank you! How exactly would the `animate` code look like?

Comment: I tried this, but it is the same like with window.scroll `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);` . Can I make with jquery in the same time a white flash?

Comment: I don't understand `Can I make with jquery in the same time a white flash?`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need jQuery to achieve this. All you need is a simple anchor tag right after the body tag.

```
<a name="anchor"> </a>
```

And to navigate there you would use.

```
 <a href="#anchor">This will send you to the anchor.</a>
```

Comment: Thank you! But I have tabs:`<!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul  role="tablist" class="summary">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#portraits" aria-controls="portraits" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Portraits</a></li></ul> <!-- Tab content --> <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="portraits">
</div>`

Comment: It should not matter. I see you have #portraits as the href so you would use <a name="portraits></a>

Comment: I put  `<a name="portraits></a>` right after the `<body>` tag, but it didn't went to the top position of the page

Comment: you are missing another " sorry my bad I forgot it <a name="portraits"></a>

Comment: It also didn't work out with `<a name="portraits"></a>`

Comment: Do this to your body tag <body id="portraits">